# How to use PHP scripts?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, php

I found a script for converting m3 files (3D models used in Starcraft 2) to obj files, but I do not know how to use it. All the information I got was "Well, here is the script.", so I cannot really give you much information, besides the fact that I have never heard of PHP before.

Here is the script

```
<?php
#########################
# $argv[1] can be edited to any custom path
#########################
  $temp = explode(".m3", $argv[1]);
    $file = $argv[1];
    $path = $temp[0];# "./Assets/Doodads/AiurTree/AiurTree_06";
    echo("Exporting Model $path to $path.obj\n\n");
    $file = fopen($file, 'rb') or die("Failed to open $file!\n");
    if(fread($file,4) != "33DM") die("Failed! File is not a StarCraft 2 model!\n");
    fseek($file, 4); # find where tags start
    $index = unpack(V, fread($file, 4));
    # search for __8U "5F 5F 38 55" tag for vertex offset
    $offset = $index[1];
    while(1){
        fseek($file, $offset+16);
        $string = fread($file, 4);
        if ($string == '__8U'){
            $offset+=20;
            break;
        }
        $offset++;
    }
    fseek($file, $offset);
    $index = unpack(V, fread($file, 4));

    fseek($file, $offset+4);
    $maxVerts = unpack(V, fread($file, 4)); # maximum extents
    $maxVerts[1] = $maxVerts[1] + $index[1];
    fseek($file, $offset+6);
    $version = unpack(V, fread($file, 4)); # up to 7 versions currently known
    if ($version[1] == 7 or $version[1] == 0){
      $EOB = 4; # versions have different number of values after uv - value to reach end of block
    } elseif ($version[1] == 1 or $version[1] == 2 or $version[1] == 3 or $version[1] == 6){
      $EOB = 8;
    } else {
      $EOB = 8;
      echo("Model not yet supported, report it to Teal\n");
      //die("Model not yet supported, report it to Teal");
    }
    echo("Model type $version[1]\n");
    if ($version[1] == 2) echo("This model will have invalid UV coordinates... working on it.\n");
    fseek($file, $offset+32); # face data
    $indexFaces = unpack(V, fread($file, 4));
    fseek($file, $offset+36);
    $maxFaces = unpack(V, fread($file, 4));
    $maxFaces[1] = $maxFaces[1]*2 + $indexFaces[1];

    $i = 0;
    $k = 0;
    $offset = $index[1];
    while(1){
      if ($offset >= $maxVerts[1]) break;
      for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){ # read verts
        fseek($file, $offset);
        $temp = unpack(f, fread($file, 4));
        $vert[$i] = $temp[1];
        $offset +=4;
        $i++;
      }
      $offset+=12;
      for($j=0;$j<2;$j++){ # read UV
        fseek($file, $offset);
        $temp = unpack(v, fread($file, 2));
        if ($temp[1] > 2046){
          $uv[$k] = $temp[1] / 65536;
        } else {
          $uv[$k] = $temp[1] / 2046;
        } 
        $offset +=2;
        $k++;
      }
      $offset+=$EOB;
    }
    $i=0;
    $offset = $indexFaces[1];
    while(1){ # read faces
      if ($offset >= $maxFaces[1]) break;
      fseek($file, $offset);
      $temp = unpack(v, fread($file, 2));
      $face[$i]=$temp[1];
      $i++;
      $offset+=2;
    }
    $out = fopen($path . ".obj", 'w+');
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($vert); $i+=3){
      fwrite($out, "v " . $vert[$i] . " " . $vert[$i+1] . " " . $vert[$i+2] . "\n");
    }
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($uv); $i+=2){
      fwrite($out, "vt " . $uv[$i] . " " . (1-$uv[$i+1]) . "\n");
    }
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($face); $i+=3){
      fwrite($out, "f " . ($face[$i]+1) . "/" . ($face[$i]+1) . " " . ($face[$i+1]+1) . "/" . ($face[$i+1]+1) . " " . ($face[$i+2]+1) . "/" . ($face[$i+2]+1) . "\n");
    }
    fclose($out);
    echo("Done!\n\n");
?>
```

How can I use this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to save the script as a file named `script.php`(or anything with `.php`). Copy everything, paste it into a text editor of your choice. Place it somewhere, probably best in `/Users/your-username/script.php`, or any other folder you like.

Now you can run the script using the `php` binary which comes with OS X.

Open the Terminal.app from *Applications → Utilities*. Enter the following line

```
php ~/script.php ~/file.m3
```

to execute the script. `~` is short for your home directory. Of course, `file.m3` needs to exist in your home directory as well and be the StarCraft file you want to convert.

The resulting `.obj` file will *probably* be placed in the same folder as the `m3` file.

Comment: Some notes: You don't *need* to name it `php`, it's just easier to spot that way. Also, the author of the script didn't really care to include a usage message, which would help you to understand the script. It runs on my Mac, but I can't test with a real file ;)

Comment: Works perfectly. The only problem is in the script itself, but, by examining the syntax, I think I have found a way to fix that. Thanks a lot!